# Measurement limitations in definite integrals over continuous variables

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals

This is a theoretical issue I found myself thinking about:

$\int p(x)dx$

is an integral of a pdf for random variable $X$,
and $\theta$ is a threshold point on that pdf

It's clear that $P(x=\theta)$=0
if $X$ is continuous

[image]

Therefore

$P(x\geq\theta)$ = $P(x>\theta)$

and

$\int_\theta^1p(x)dx$ = 1 - $\int_0^\theta p(x)dx$

However this may get complicated when you are working with actual measurement limitations: Suppose $X$ is the measurements in a medical test, with above $\theta$ threshold for positives.

In theory getting a test result of exactly $\theta$ is improbable, but in actual reality this can happen even when $X$ is continuous, because of finite rating scales, or measurement accuracy limitations.

A sample of 10 subject with the following results:

3 below $\theta$,
2 measure exactly $\theta$,
5 positives (above $\theta$)

Remember, $\int_\theta^1p(x)dx$ = 1 - $\int_0^\theta p(x)dx$

but according to the above sample:

$\int_\theta^1p(x)dx$= 0.7

1 - $\int_0^\theta p(x)dx$ = 0.5

**Since the the difference is derived from the two $\theta$ rated measures, doesn't this imply that inclusivity considerations be taken when defining the interval?**

**And if not, can this integration issue of measurements limitations be resolved within a continuous definition of $X$?**

Comment: If you have such a small sample, perhaps continuous approximation is not applicable? Can you use the summation instead?

Comment: You're assuming a discrete model (with a non parametric estimate), hence you must use counting measure (summation).

Comment: Alex, the sample is just to make a point - this is a theoretical question, this can be applied to a much larger sample. My main question here is how do you treat continuous variables when your measuring capabilities eventually confine you to specific values. Giovanni, this is also why I did not resolve to a discrete model. Such a situation can happen, for instance, when integrating an ROC curve with a finite number of thresholds.